# Possible to stop Wordpress from adding p1, p2… classes to p tags in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I've noticed the first time today that WP is adding numbered class names (p1,p2…) to my p tags.

I have the following TinyMCE init related part in the functions.php.

```
function my_mce( $init ) {
    $init['block_formats'] = "Paragraph=p; Heading 3=h3; Heading 4=h4";

    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Link',
            'selector' => 'a',
            'classes' => 'link'
        )
    );
    $init['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce');
```

In my php an example snippet (using ACF options field) looks like that:

```
  <div class="dataprivacy__feature">
    <h3 class="lat-bn">Google Analytics</h3>
    <?php the_field('op-dataprivacy-analytics', 'option'); ?>
  </div>
```

The outputted p tag get the p1 class:

```
<div class="dataprivacy__feature">
    <h3 class="lat-bn">Google Analytics</h3>
    <p class="p1">Privacy statement</p>
    <p class="p1 link">More <a title="Google Privacy" href="http://www.google.de/intl/de/privacy/" target="_blank">infos</a>.</p>
  </div>
```

Is it possible to prevent that?

Comment: I have the same issue happening. It seems to show up in the code itself, you can see it in the 'Text' tab in the WYSIWYG. Tried deleting it, tried clearing the formatting, but it just comes right back after saving the post.

Comment: Same issue. It seems to happen when copy & pasting from a rich text application such as Apple Mail or Pages. It doesn't happen when pasting from a plain text app. I've seen reports of this on the TinyMCE forums, so I think it's a TinyMCE issue, not WP specific. Are you using OS X? I'm wondering if it might even be OS specific which is why more people are not complaining about it?

Comment: I'm also getting these classes on everything. `<h3 class='h2 h3'>`  and the classes double up as well. I would really like NO classes added without my permission.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out how to strip those classes using TinyMCE's `paste_preprocess` option.

In your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'customize_tinymce');

function customize_tinymce($in) {
  $in['paste_preprocess'] = "function(pl,o){ o.content = o.content.replace(/p class=\"p[0-9]+\"/g,'p'); o.content = o.content.replace(/span class=\"s[0-9]+\"/g,'span'); }";
  return $in;
}
```

The value passed to paste_preprocess is a JavaScript function which will be executed whenever content is pasted into TinyMCE. The function uses a regular expression to strip instances of e.g. `class="p1"` and `class="s1"` on `p` and `span` tags.

Note that this is for WordPress 4.x, which uses TinyMCE 4.

I'd still love to know where those classes originate. It's odd that multiple applications append exactly the same classes to HTML tags...